# Why file buffer doesn't copy to the bss buffer in Assembly?

Tags: file, assembly, buffer

Today I tried to copy file buffer to my buffer.

When i was using buffer in data section it was working, but when I tried to do this with bss section (this is propably better for this), this not working.

This is my open/read/close/display code:

```
; Load media
mov ax, 3D02h
lea dx, [fileName] ; in data segment: fileName: db 'sprite.pbm', 0
int 21h ; it works
jc _end
mov bx, ax

push ds
mov ah, 3Fh
mov cx, 400h
mov ax, bss
mov ds, ax
lea dx, [fileBuffer] ; in bss segment: fileBuffer: resb 1024
int 21h
jc _end
pop ds

mov ah, 3Eh
int 21h

push ds
mov ah, 09h
mov ax, bss
mov ds, ax
lea dx, [fileBuffer]
int 21h ; I tried to display fileBuffer but fileBuffer is clear propably
pop ds
```

Comment: Hahaha, yeeees! But i cant resolve it, this not have sense

Comment: `mov ax, bss` of course destroys `ah` that you set earlier, you should swap the order. PS: learn to use a debugger (assuming it doesn't take away your fun ...)

Comment: @Jester Can you stop already with these comments? They help absolutely nobody.

Comment: Yeah sorry I solved another of his problems, I'll stop. PS: he clearly got the joke, that you apparently didn't.

Comment: @Jester Holy moly, its working better. I wanna use debugger but i cant find any 16-bit version

Comment: turbo debugger for example was a common one.

Comment: Lol, how i didnt find them. Thank you very much